# Display the result in one page layout view page

Tags: layout, shipping, product-view

we need to display shipping charges on product view page.

so we are using custom module , its working fine in default magento.

in that module there is an option to display shipping charges in **Left column or Right column** , according to configuration we set in backend

[image]

but for our theme by default we are using **1 page layout**.

is there any way that we can display the shipping charges in our case [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html).

is we have to provide one more option in backend for "1 page layout" ?

config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                <class>WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model</class>
            </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                <class>WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Block</class>
            </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                <class>WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Helper</class>
            </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>productpageshipping</frontName>
                    <module>WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping</module>
                </args>
            </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
        </routers>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <model>webdevlopers_productpageshipping/observer</model>
                        <method>observeLayoutHandleInitialization</method>
                    </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
                    <file>productpageshipping.xml</file>
                </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <webdevlopers>
        <productshippingpage>
            <controller_actions>
                <catalog_product_view />
            </controller_actions>
        </productshippingpage>
    </webdevlopers>
    <default>
        <webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
            <settings>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
                <display_position>left</display_position>
                <use_country>1</use_country>
                <use_region>1</use_region>
                <use_city>1</use_city>
                <use_postcode>1</use_postcode>
                <use_coupon_code>1</use_coupon_code>
                <use_cart>1</use_cart>
                <use_cart_default>0</use_cart_default>
            </settings>
            <message>
                <blocktitle>ESTIMATE SHIPPING</blocktitle>
                <blockdec>Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.</blockdec>
                <shippingblocktitle>SHIPPING RATES</shippingblocktitle>
                <result>There are no shipping method applied for your destination.</result>
                <button>Get a Quote</button>
            </message>
        </webdevlopers_productpageshipping>
    </default>
</config>
```

**observer.php**

```
<?php

class WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model_Observer
{

    protected $_config = null;


    public function getConfig()
    {
        if ($this->_config === null) {
            $this->_config = Mage::getSingleton('webdevlopers_productpageshipping/config');
        }

        return $this->_config;
    }


    public function observeLayoutHandleInitialization(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $controllerAction Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action */
        $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
        $fullActionName = $controllerAction->getFullActionName();
        if ($this->getConfig()->isEnabled() && in_array($fullActionName, $this->getConfig()->getControllerActions())) {
            if ($this->getConfig()->getDisplayPosition() === WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model_Config::DISPLAY_POSITION_LEFT) {
                // Display the form in the left column on the page
                $controllerAction->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle(
                    WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model_Config::LAYOUT_HANDLE_LEFT
                );
            } elseif ($this->getConfig()->getDisplayPosition() === WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model_Config::DISPLAY_POSITION_RIGHT) {
                // Display the form in the right column on the page
                $controllerAction->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle(
                    WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Model_Config::LAYOUT_HANDLE_RIGHT
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: paste this function from observer observeLayoutHandleInitialization

Comment: check the updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following code in view.phtml :

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping.estimate.form'); ?>`

I added following code in xml as like this :

```
<webdevlopers_productpageshipping_estimate_estimate>
        <block type="webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate_result" name="shipping.estimate.result" template="webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/result.phtml" output="toHtml" />
    </webdevlopers_productpageshipping_estimate_estimate>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
          <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><file>css/productpageshipping.css</file></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info">
              <block name="shipping.estimate.form" type="webdevlopers_productpageshipping/estimate_form" template="webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```